# how to select the particular string from the list in the textview using gtk2.0

Tags: gtk2

I have implemented to read and display the image contents from file in textview of GUI application(gtk2.0).
As a next step, I need to select text of a particular line from the textview and once it is selected it should display the corresponding image of the text.

Can anyone please share the related C code on this.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking; what's the image of the text?

Comment: image is  four wheeler eu based license plate number

Comment: Can you back up and explain more clearly what you are trying to do? I'm afraid it will be difficult to answer this question. You have images, each associated with a text string, and you are displaying them all in a text view?